# Xam.Plugin.Media TakeVideoAsync ignores Quality setting

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm using https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Media v5.0.1 to get videos for my app.

Calling TakeVideoAsync method with StoreVideoOptions.Quality set to any valid value is ignored.
The generated file has always the same size.

My goal is to be able to create low-quality, smaller videos.

Any missing information that I should consider?

Testing on physical device LGE Nexus 5x with Android 8.1

Xam.Forms 4.8.0.1364

Xam.Plugin.Media v5.0.1

Comment: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/issues/406

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Jason, any alternative for this that would not include platform specific development?

Comment: generally, using a platform specific feature like a camera requires platform specific code